# NestedScrollView and RecyclerView no scroll even though they're not nested?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a really weird issue I've never experienced before.

So, I have a view (BottomSheet) that encapsulates a `RecyclerView` and its empty view. I put one of them as `View.GONE` and the other as `View.VISIBLE`, depending on if there are items to show or not.
The empty view is actually wrapped in a `NestedScrollView` because I need to be able to scroll it for the user to be able to move the BottomSheet up or down.

The problem is that, depending on how I structure the view, the scroll is actually on the `RecyclerView` or the `NestedScrollView`, whichever I put first, and not both. Their parent is a `RelativeLayout` (take a look at the code below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/BottomSheet"
    >

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.myproject.CustomRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="36dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:emptyView="@id/empty_view"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_below="@id/header"` where's the header? `android:visibility="gone"
tools:visibility="visible"` why do you have two of these

Comment: I edited the question accordingly, the view is actually a bit more complex, but this is the core of the problem (if I put exactly this, I get the same problem). I have ```android:visibility="gone"``` to hide the view on startup, but ```tools:visibility="visible"``` because it lets me see if the empty view is OK design-wise

Answer (score 1):

**1.- Put in your NestedScrollView this :**

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Now what kinda problem occurred when we used nestedScrollView and put recyclerView inside nestedScrollView, it scrolls in various speed depending on gesture. The scrolling feature will not be smooth.

**2.-So to fix this issue all you have to do after setting your adapter
put this line:**

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

Now your recyclerview will work with smooth scrolling…

I hope It will help you!

Comment: Try to use coordynaitorlayout

Comment: Yes, I already tried that too, I also tried LinearLayout with no luck

Comment: But add your recycler inside the nested

Comment: That's very dangerous, because if you wrap a recyclerview inside a nestedscrollview, then the recyclerview will bind all the items at once, as the nestedscrollview needs the full height of the child view to work. That's why I separated them and why you should never put a recyclerview as a nestedscrollview's child

Comment: I gave this answer because you need it. And I know about that problem. That's why I sayed 2 steps. You can use as well android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" on your recycler

Comment: I understand, and I appreciate it, I just don't want to put the RV as the NestedScrollView's child

Comment: I will keep your question for the future . I'll try to find the solution anyway .